# Continuity of a piecewise Function (left-continuous/right-continuous)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have to determine the points where the following function is continuous, left-continuous or right-continuous:

$g(x):= \begin{cases}-1 & \text { if } x \geq 1 \\ \frac{1}{n} & \text { if } \exists n \in \mathbb{N}: \frac{1}{n+1} \leq x<\frac{1}{n} \\ 0 & \text { if } x \leq 0\end{cases}$

I have already found out that gg is continuous at all $x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash\left\{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ and right-continuous at all $x \in\left\{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$. But I don’t know how to justify this formally and rigorously. How can I calculate the limits of g at the points x=0 and $x=\frac{1}{n}$​ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the proof for continuity at $x=0$. You may ty to imitate it and show discontinuity at $x=\frac{1}{n}$.

Given $\epsilon>0$, select $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ s.t. $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, i.e. $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$. We claim: $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$ corresponds to this $\epsilon$-challenge, or more precisely, if $0<|x|<\frac{1}{n}$, then \begin{equation} |g(x)-g(0)|<\epsilon\cdots(\star).\end{equation} Since $g(0)=0$, we have
$$(\star)\iff |g(x)|<\epsilon.$$

Now we justify
$$|g(x)|<\epsilon\cdots(\star\star). $$

In fact, if $x$ is a fixed real number s.t. $0<|x|<\frac{1}{n}$ and $x<0$, then $|g(x)|=0<\epsilon$, $(\star\star) $ is correct for *this* $x$; if $x$ is a fixed real number s.t. $0<|x|<\frac{1}{n}$ and $x>0$, then exists $m\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, $\frac{1}{m+1}\le x<\frac{1}{m}$. Since $x<\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{m+1}\le x$, we have $\frac{1}{m+1}<\frac{1}{n}\implies n<m+1$, i.e. $n\le m$. Therefore $g(x)=\frac{1}{m}\le \frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$, $(\star\star) $ is correct for *this* $x$. Therefore $g$ is continuous at $x=0$.

---

You may wonder how we come up with letting $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$. This is because if  $0<x<\frac{1}{n}$, then $g(x)<\frac{1}{n}$. So we select $n$ s.t. $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$ and let $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$.